# Filling path with image by Raphael on IPAD shows clipped and upside-down pattern

Tags: image, ipad, svg, raphael, fill

I am working on a web project drawing 2D floorplan on iPad. 
I chose raphael library to do the work.
Now I just had a problem which only occurs on iPad.

I simply draw the floorplan with paper.path() method in Raphael.js and then render the floor by filling the path with image.
The code is very simple, as follows:

```
mFloor = paper.path('M ' + mPoints).attr('fill','url(img/wood1.jpg)');
```

Here mPoints is an array of points [x,y] indicating the positions of all the corners of the room.

the original image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDaOo.png

This is the screenshot of the rendering result on iPad, it clearly shows that the original image has been randomly clipped into three parts and then randomly combined to fill the path.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJONm.png

This problem only occurs on iPad while on PC the image correctly and accurately fills the path in Safari and Chrome.

Does iOS have a problem to support pattern-filling?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663872/why-are-the-svg-image-fills-on-http-justplay-thefa-com-upside-down-in-ios4

Comment: Yes, I already tried that. It helped me to fix the problem of upside down but the image is still randomly clipped and combined together.